# Error Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined

Tags: javascript, ajax

I was trying to get the input item alphabet auto populate list, but when I want to search something it shows inside console

> Cannot read property 'toLowerCase' of undefined

Here is my code through which i want to populate a dropdown search items

```js
// Do the actual search
function run_search(query) {
  var cache_key = query + computeURL();
  var cached_results = cache.get(cache_key);
  if (cached_results) {
    if ($.isFunction($(input).data("settings").onCachedResult)) {
      cached_results = $(input).data("settings").onCachedResult.call(hiddenInput, cached_results);
    }
    populateDropdown(query, cached_results);
  } else {
    // Are we doing an ajax search or local data search?
    if ($(input).data("settings").url) {
      var url = computeURL();
      // Extract existing get params
      var ajax_params = {};
      ajax_params.data = {};
      if (url.indexOf("?") > -1) {
        var parts = url.split("?");
        ajax_params.url = parts[0];

        var param_array = parts[1].split("&");
        $.each(param_array, function(index, value) {
          var kv = value.split("=");
          ajax_params.data[kv[0]] = kv[1];
        });
      } else {
        ajax_params.url = url;
      }

      // Prepare the request
      ajax_params.data[$(input).data("settings").queryParam] = query;
      ajax_params.type = $(input).data("settings").method;
      ajax_params.dataType = $(input).data("settings").contentType;
      if ($(input).data("settings").crossDomain) {
        ajax_params.dataType = "jsonp";
      }

      // exclude current tokens?
      // send exclude list to the server, so it can also exclude existing tokens
      if ($(input).data("settings").excludeCurrent) {
        var currentTokens = $(input).data("tokenInputObject").getTokens();
        var tokenList = $.map(currentTokens, function(el) {
          if (typeof $(input).data("settings").tokenValue == 'function')
            return $(input).data("settings").tokenValue.call(this, el);

          return el[$(input).data("settings").tokenValue];
        });

        ajax_params.data[$(input).data("settings").excludeCurrentParameter] = tokenList.join($(input).data("settings").tokenDelimiter);
      }

      // Attach the success callback
      ajax_params.success = function(results) {
        cache.add(cache_key, $(input).data("settings").jsonContainer ? results[$(input).data("settings").jsonContainer] : results);
        if ($.isFunction($(input).data("settings").onResult)) {
          results = $(input).data("settings").onResult.call(hiddenInput, results);
        }

        // only populate the dropdown if the results are associated with the active search query
        if (input_box.val() === query) {
          populateDropdown(query, $(input).data("settings").jsonContainer ? results[$(input).data("settings").jsonContainer] : results);
        }
      };

      // Provide a beforeSend callback
      if (settings.onSend) {
        settings.onSend(ajax_params);
      }

      // Make the request
      $.ajax(ajax_params);
    } else if ($(input).data("settings").local_data) {
      // Do the search through local data
      var results = $.grep($(input).data("settings").local_data, function(row) {
        return row[$(input).data("settings").propertyToSearch].toLowerCase().indexOf(query.toLowerCase());
      });

      cache.add(cache_key, results);
      if ($.isFunction($(input).data("settings").onResult)) {
        results = $(input).data("settings").onResult.call(hiddenInput, results);
      }
      populateDropdown(query, results);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: `row[$(input).data("settings").propertyToSearch]` is `undefined`, why is that we can't say, as there's not all the related code in the post (or you're never passing `query` to the function).

Comment: yeah i did passing the `query` to the function.. but why m facing that undefined issue?

Comment: and how this `row[$(input).data("settings").propertyToSearch] ` can be defined?

Comment: `row` is an object/array, and the property name/index to read is formed within a `data-settings` attribute of a first element on the page, (what is inside `input` variable, isn't defined in your code),  which you assume to have `propertyToSearch` property (which most likely is not the case, as everything you get from the DOM is string). Like said, we need more code to resolve all the references on that line.

Comment: We don't need all the code, see [mcve].

Comment: https://textuploader.com/18k0k here is the code you can find of my work

Comment: No, please read the linked Help article. We're not here to do your job, we're only helping you to get your job done. That means you should just not post/link to a bunch of a code, you should strip all the irrelevant code so, that the problem can still be reproduced. Simplify the logic, make fake data etc. to narrow down the code, and post that example.

Comment: sir i m very new to the javascript and i put the portion in the question .. but for your need i put the code which is need for you to see where i m getting the problem and how?

Comment: Do you seriously think, that someone would go through 39 kB of code, study how it works and then debug it for you, all this voluntarily and for free ..? You've to make your part of the job, define only the necessary variables and data to reproduce the issue. It shouldn't be too hard for this case, just follow your own logic, and use the final result in the example with the appropriate data only. Use console to log the data, or break points in the debugger to see what you have in different stages of your code.